# Adding up a value after matching a line using append from a text file using python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, text, time

I have a text file which contains lines as followed

```
Data_1 (2): 01 sec
Data_1 (1): 01 sec
Data_1 (1): 02 secs
Data_2 (2): 04 secs
Data_1 (3, 1, 2): 2 hrs 40 mins 02 secs
Data_2 (1): 03 secs
Data_1 (3, 1, 2): 20 secs
Data_3 (1): 02 secs
Data_3 (2): 23 secs
```

I want my output to be like:

```
Data_1 (2): 01 sec
Data_1 (1): 03 secs
Data_2 (2): 04 secs
Data_1 (3, 1, 2): 2 hrs 40 mins 22 secs
```

Just adding up the seconds if values in each line till ":" matches with each other the seconds values should be summed up irrespective of the position they are located.

Code till now:

```
with open("folder/file_1", "r") as total_timing:
    variable_number = len(variable_name)
    evaluated_variables = []
    timing = 0
    for val, line in zip(range(0,variable_number),total_timing):
        if variable_name[val] in line:
            value = int((line.split(":")[1]).split()[0])
            timing = value + timing
            if variable_name[val] not in evaluated_variables:
                print("   > " + variable_name[val] + " " + str(timing))
                evaluated_variables.append(variable_name[val])
```

I have got `variable_name` from another loop where I retrieve the variables. But this code doesn't provide what I require. Any help would really great...!

Comment: Why do you sum up the two `Data_1 (3, 1, 2)` lines, even though there's a `Data_2 (1)` between them?

Comment: @Kevin I want to sum up all the values which match before ":" irrespective of their positions....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest approach is to split each line into a name string and a time integer. Then you can store the cumulative values in an ordered dict and output them once they're all added up.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
d = OrderedDict()
with open("folder/file_1") as file:
    for line in file:
        name, _, raw_time = line.rpartition(":")
        time = int(raw_time.strip("sec \n"))
        d[name] = d.get(name,0) + time

for name, time in d.items():
    print("{}: {:02} {}".format(name, time, "sec" if time == 1 else "secs"))
```

Result:

```
Data_1 (2): 01 sec
Data_1 (1): 03 secs
Data_2 (2): 04 secs
Data_1 (3, 1, 2): 04 secs
Data_2 (1): 03 secs
Data_3 (1): 02 secs
Data_3 (2): 23 secs
```

Comment: This works perfectly except a missing bracket in print statement

Comment: Oops, sorry. I wrote it in Python 2.7, where `print` doesn't require brackets :-)

Comment: I ended up in a small issue.... For another data I have something like "01 min 27 secs" this shows an error. How can I also accept min and hours in this implementation like "1 hr 10 mins 20 secs"

Comment: You'd have to replace the `time = ` line with more complicated logic that can convert the hours/minutes/seconds string into an integer representing the total number of seconds elapsed. I bet there's a bunch of posts on Stack Overflow that describe how you can do that.

Comment: Thank you :) Is it possible to edit the answer to accept minutes and seconds value too

Comment: @user3703782 This is not related to your original problem which is general parsing of rows and mapping them to dictionaries. This is a different sub-problem you can find a solution to very easily. Possibly using a function to parse the time part of the row.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#  coding: utf-8

with open("data.txt", "r") as f:
  timings_totals =  {}
  for l in f:
    key, rest = l.split(": ")
    timing = int(rest.split(" ")[0])
    timings_totals[key] = timings_totals.get(key, 0) + timing

for k,v in timings_totals.items():
  print("{}: {} secs".format(k, v))
```